# Variable is accessed within inner class, needs to be declared final

Tags: android, button, onclick

I'm trying to make a button compare its value to some other variable. In the onClick method i get an error saying Variable is accessed within inner class, needs to be declared final. The problem is that the variable is supposed to be changed, so i cannot make it final. How can i fix this? Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GameActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);    

        int partA = 9;
        int partB = 9;
        int correctAnswer = partA * partB;
        int wrongAnswer1 = correctAnswer++;
        int wrongAnswer2 = correctAnswer--;

        TextView textObjectA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPartA);
        TextView textObjectB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPartB);

        Button buttonObjectChoice1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice1);
        Button buttonObjectChoice2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice2);
        Button buttonObjectChoice3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice3);


        buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + correctAnswer);
        buttonObjectChoice2.setText("" + wrongAnswer1);
        buttonObjectChoice3.setText("" + wrongAnswer2);    

        buttonObjectChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + buttonObjectChoice1.getText());

                if(correctAnswer==answerGiven)  {

                }
            }
        });
        buttonObjectChoice1.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonObjectChoice1.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    public void onClick(View view)  {}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

1. Make `buttonObjectChoice1` `final`:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       final Button buttonObjectChoice1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice1);
       ...
       buttonObjectChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

              int answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + buttonObjectChoice1.getText());

               ...
           }
       });
   }
   ```
2. Convert view at runtime:

   ```
   buttonObjectChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           final Button btn = (Button)v;

           int answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + btn.getText());

           ...
        }
   });
   ```

Advantage of approach 2 is, it will reduce workload of compiler to generate accessor methods to access buttonObjectChoice1 object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the variables as private field of your class and update it accordingly in the method.